# Hosting a 32bit OCX inside a 64bit process (specifically Flash)

Tags: windows, flash, winapi, 64-bit, ocx

We are in the process of building a 64bit version of our software, but we use Flash player's OCX control to host Flash in our windows. This OCX file is a 32bit build, do you know if it's possible to host this 32bit version of Flash within our 64bit application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly possible... Firefox has 64 bit versions that embed the 32 bit Flash player.  On Linux, this is accomplished by nspluginwrapper, which is open source so perhaps you can figure out how they do it.  There must be something similar for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that loading 32-bit DLLs into 64-bit processes is supported by Windows. An OCX is a DLL with a different extension.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some kind of external (COM) host process